# Adding observations having same column and create one unique row for each observation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am having a dataset as shown below:

```
          batsman                 batting_team  2008  2009  2010  2011  2012  2013  2014  2015  2016  2017  2018
0  A Ashish Reddy              Deccan Chargers     0     0     0     0    35     0     0     0     0     0     0
1  A Ashish Reddy          Sunrisers Hyderabad     0     0     0     0     0   125     0    73    47     0     0
2      A Chandila             Rajasthan Royals     0     0     0     0     0     4     0     0     0     0     0
3        A Chopra        Kolkata Knight Riders    42    11     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
4     A Choudhary  Royal Challengers Bangalore     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0    25     0
```

I am trying to add the columns with same name as per their scores in each year, also, for example, if A Ready is appearing two times, that means,

I am just trying to add to create if else, but not able to get anywhere.

we create one observation from these two, as the following

Name - A Reddy

Team - second observation team name

2008,2009,...,2018 -  and add columns data from year columns.

Comment: Can you post a desired output for this snippet?  It sounds you just want `df.groupby('batsman').sum()`

Comment: I need the output in years column, as it gives, your code, but I also want the batting team column and the value replcecd with new latest batting column entry.

Comment: Try this: `u = df.groupby('batsman'); pd.concat([u.sum(), u['batting_team'].last()], axis=1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
df_out = df.groupby('batsman').sum()
#Sums all numeric columns of the dataframe

df_out['batting_team'] = df_out.index.map(df.drop_duplicates(['batsman'], keep='last').set_index('batsman')['batting_team'])
#Use drop duplicates to keep the last team and set_index to use in map 

df_out.reset_index().reindex(df.columns, axis=1)
#Reset index and reorder dataframe columns like input dataframe
```

Output:

```
          batsman                 batting_team  2008  2009  2010  2011  2012  2013  2014  2015  2016  2017  2018
0  A Ashish Reddy          Sunrisers Hyderabad     0     0     0     0    35   125     0    73    47     0     0
1      A Chandila             Rajasthan Royals     0     0     0     0     0     4     0     0     0     0     0
2        A Chopra        Kolkata Knight Riders    42    11     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
3     A Choudhary  Royal Challengers Bangalore     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0    25     0
```